# How to know if a google account is under a google apps domain?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I am working on an app that allows user to share their Drive files to friends. But there is a problem of Google App Account, like `someone@somadomain.com`, of which files cannot be shared with people who are not under that domain. Although the share policy can be changed by admin of `somedomain.com`, but I prefer not allowing people use my app with Google Apps Account.

I also check this post: [How to determine if the account is a Google apps account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598846/how-to-determine-if-the-account-is-a-google-apps-account). But I don't agree with the idea of checking domain to detect account type. Because people can register Google Account with any email address. I just registered one with my Hotmail, `someone@hotmail.com`, which has no domain restriction when sharing a file.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: I have my own domain and use it as Google Apps domain just for using Gmail as mail provider. I am using my Apps mail address as my private account, just like others use the @gmail.com account. And I know quite a few people doing essentially the same. May I ask you to reconsider your idea and treat us Apps users just like regular users?

Comment: @HelmuthB, thanks for your feedback. I do agree that some people using Google accounts as their private account. But, is it weird that when you share a photo with your friend, he have to be in the same domain to see that _public_ photo? I will reconsider it, and try to find a workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you included:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

in your OAuth scopes, you can make a request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
```

If it's a Google Apps account, an "hd" parameter (Hosted Domain?) will be returned by the call with the Google Apps domain as it's value. If it's a consumer account, whether it's @gmail.com or even a potential "conflicting account", the hd parameter will not be returned. See my example below. admin@jay.powerposters.org is a Google Apps Account while consumer@jay.powerposters.org is a consumer account. If I created a consumer user in the Google Apps domain it wouuld become a conflicting account and the consumer account would be pushed out of the @jay.powerposters.org namespace but that hasn't happened yet.

For admin@jay.powerposters.org:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 99
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
...

{
 "email": "admin@jay.powerposters.org",
 "verified_email": true,
 "hd": "jay.powerposters.org"
}
```

For consumer@jay.powerposters.org:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 71
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

{
 "email": "consumer@jay.powerposters.org",
 "verified_email": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to check if an account is a Google Apps account. The only way I'm thinking of is to check the Domain's DNS MX records and see if some service of the domain are served by Google Apps servers (like email served from gmail etc...) but even there you might have to check more than one service because some Google Apps companies deactivate Gmail for instance (or some other service) to use a custom solution instead.

If I were you I would not disable the service to Google Apps accounts (how unfair!! :)) many people bought Google Apps account to have a nice looking email domain and their account behave just like any other Google Accounts...

I would simply try to set the ACL of the fils to public when you need to and if this does not work display them with a nice error message warning them about their Admin having disabled public sharing... It's not going to be lots of users anyways and it would be too bad to have your app not available to others "normal" Google Apps accounts.

Answer (score -2):

Or check the domain using a service like [BrowserSpy](http://browserspy.dk/googleapps.php). If the MX records appear correct, then it's using Google Apps.