# How to know if an account has the authorization to share to the web?

Tags: google-drive-api

I know you can modified the permissions with this route :

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

But I met a problem if the user is a Google Apps Account. If the user doesn't have the right to share a document to the web, the sharing is broken (you're redirected to a web page asking you to login to a google apps account of the domain).

I found the parameter 'domainSharingPolicy' here :

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource

But it isn't really consistent. You can have the string 'allowed' or 'allowedWithWarning' it doesn't really allow you.

So my question is, how to know if the account is a Google Apps account ? (yes I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517551/how-to-know-if-a-google-account-is-under-a-google-apps-domain))

And/Or, How to know if the account has the right to share a document to the web ? (not to the organization only).