# How to selectively add scopes for Google Apps accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I want to be able to use certain scopes required by [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) during OAuth for all Google accounts added to my service. However, some of these scopes are not relevant for free Gmail accounts.

Now, one option would be to have a separate flow in our service itself such that we make it apparent to the user that Google Apps and Gmail are different. But from previous experiences, I've seen that quite a few users are not savvy enough to differentiate between the two and just go ahead with Gmail flow anyway and these users would end up missing out on features which we could've provided had he/she gone for the Google Apps flow.

I'd rather avoid this and make things as simple as possible for a user. To that end, is there any way I can specify "*Add **this** scope if this is a Google Apps account"*, during the 1st leg itself?

Comment: 1. I am not really sure there is a way to figure out if its an apps account after the user has authenticated.  2. If you can then there is a way to request additional scopes once you have authenticated.  3. Its possible but no idea how you have yours coded https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit` scope.

Even if you do include this scope to be authorized by the user you will not get any errors during the flow regardless if they are a free gmail account or a non G Suite administrator. Only if you call an API which requires the `admin.directory.orgunit` scope as a non G Suite administrator will you receive an error.

If you are concerned that your users might be deterred from using your app if you ask for too many scopes you can [request additional scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth) when the need arises.

[If you want to detect if a user is a free gmail or a G Suite account check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401202). After which you could ask for additional scopes if it's a G Suite account.

Comment: I understand that adding directory scopes will not result in any errors, but free Gmail users will also end up seeing that permission in the OAuth consent screen which I wanted to avoid. The idea of requesting for additional scopes after detecting if it is hosted domain sounds like a plan :)